# cloudwatch(カスタムメトリクス)の値がawscliで取得できない

Tags: aws, aws-cli

CentOS7へSSM Agentをインストールし、SSM経由でAWS-ConfigureAWSPackageをインストールしました。

パラメータストアにJSONファイルをUploadした上で、AmazonCloudWatch-ManageAgentで、
インストールを行い問題なく完了することができました。
その後、CWAgentというNAMESPACEが登録され、CloudWatchの画面上では値が取れていることが確認できております。

またAWSCLIを使用してカスタムメトリクスの値を取得しようと試したところ、値が返ってこない状況です。
なお、通常の標準メトリクス（AWS/EC2などは）取得することができました。
※取得する期間の問題かと思い長く設定しましたが、それでも取得できません。

---

標準メトリクス（AWS/EC2）

```
$ aws cloudwatch get-metric-statistics --metric-name CPUUtilization --start-time 2018-10-16T09:25:00 --end-time 2018-10-16T09:40:00 --period 60 --namespace AWS/EC2 --statistics Maximum --dimensions Name=InstanceId,Value=＊＊＊＊＊＊＊＊＊＊＊＊＊＊＊

{
  "Datapoints": [
    {
      "Timestamp": "2018-10-16T09:32:00Z",
      "Maximum": 0.666666666666664,
      "Unit": "Percent"
    },
    {
      "Timestamp": "2018-10-16T09:27:00Z",
      "Maximum": 8.16666666666667,
      "Unit": "Percent"
    },
    {
      "Timestamp": "2018-10-16T09:37:00Z",
      "Maximum": 0.66666666666667,
      "Unit": "Percent"
    }
  ],
  "Label": "CPUUtilization"
}
```

---

カスタムメトリクス（CWAgent）

```
$ aws cloudwatch get-metric-statistics --metric-name mem_used_percent --start-time 2018-10-16T09:25:00 --end-time 2018-10-16T09:40:00 --period 60 --namespace CWAgent/EC2 --statistics Maximum --dimensions Name=InstanceId,Value=＊＊＊＊＊＊＊＊＊＊＊＊＊＊＊
{
  "Datapoints": [], 
  "Label": "mem_used_percent"
}
```

---

取得できない理由として考えられる原因はありますでしょうか。

宜しくお願い致します。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

直感では、指定してるディメンションが不足してないか気になります。

CloudWatch GetMetricStatistics API 呼び出しがデータポイントを返さない理由。
https://aws.amazon.com/jp/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudwatch-getmetricstatistics-data/

> ディメンション
>
> メトリックは複数の寸法で測定され、そのメトリックのデータポイントはすべての設定された寸法を指定することによってのみ取得できます。たとえば、次のプロパティーをもつ DataCenterMetric 名前空間で ServerStats という名前のメトリックを公開するとします。
>
> Dimensions: Server=Prod, Domain=Frankfurt, Unit: Count, Timestamp: 2016-10-31T12:30:00Z, Value: 105
>
> これらの寸法を指定することで、このメトリックのデータポイントを取得できます。
>
> Server=Prod,Domain=Frankfurt
>
> しかし、2 つの寸法のうちの 1 つしか指定しなかった場合には、データポイントを取得できません。以下に例を示します。
>
> Server=Prod
>
> AWS コマンドラインインターフェイス (AWS CLI) により、get-metric-statistics コマンドで寸法を指定する形式は、put-metric-data コマンドの形式と異なります。次の形式と類似する形式を使用してください。
>
> "Name"=string, "Value"=string
>
> 次の形式の代わりに:
>
> Name=Value
>
> get-metric-statistics 呼び出しの例:
>
> aws cloudwatch get-metric-statistics --metric-name "MyMetric" --start-time 2018-04-08T23:18:00Z --end-time 2018-04-09T23:18:00Z --period 3600 --namespace "MyNamespace" --statistics Maximum --dimensions Name=Server,Value=Prod
>
> put-metric-data 呼び出しの例:
>
> aws cloudwatch put-metric-data --namespace "MyNamespace" --metric-name "MyMetric" --dimensions Server=Prod --value 10

問題なければ、ナレッジには、他の問題についても書かれてますので、当てはまるものがないか確認してみてください。